# std::sort problem on solaris (libCstd)

Tags: c++, stl, solaris, sunstudio

I have a problem on Solaris using the Sun Studio compiler, which is most likely due to the strange STL implementation (*libCstd*) used, see http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/cmp_stlport_libCstd.html. Consider this:

```
std::vector<C*> v;
// .. populate the vector
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

where `C` is some class. This produces the following compiler error message:

```
"/opt/sunstudio12.1/prod/include/CC/Cstd/./algorithm", line 725: Error: The operand "*first" cannot be assigned to.
"/opt/sunstudio12.1/prod/include/CC/Cstd/./algorithm.cc", line 985:     Where: While instantiating "std::__linear_insert<C*const*, C*>(C*const*, C*const*, C**)".
"/opt/sunstudio12.1/prod/include/CC/Cstd/./algorithm.cc", line 985:     Where: Instantiated from std::__insertion_sort<C*const*>(C*const*, C*const*).
"/opt/sunstudio12.1/prod/include/CC/Cstd/./algorithm", line 811:     Where: Instantiated from non-template code.
```

Does anybody know how to circumvent the problem? Of course, actually I want to use `std::sort` with a custom comparison functor, but even this simple version does not work.

Comment: Can you post what C looks like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your actual vector is const. Is it a member variable accessed in a const member function? Is it a const function argument?

Comment: stupid me. Thanks a lot! I was so focused on 'It is certainly again this stupid STL implementation'... sorry about bothering everybody.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct C {};

int main()
{
    std::vector<C*> v;
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

compiles without error with

```
CC: Sun C++ 5.9 SunOS_sparc Patch 124863-19 2009/12/02
```

invoked as

```
CC lytenyn.cpp
```